# Laravel 5.5 - Return hasMany results from another hasMany

Tags: laravel

I am getting all memberships in a Laravel 5.5 API route like this...

```
$membership= Membership::with('user')->findOrFail($id);

return Response::json(array(
        'error' => false,
        'user_data' => $membership,
    ));
```

I have a Membership hasMany Users relationship setup so this correctly returns all users belonging to this membership.

I also have a Users hasMany Images relationship setup, is there a way I can also return a list of all images that belong to the returned users?

Should I be creating a seperate function that compiles a list or can it be done directly from the with statement?

Comment: Subscription is the same as Membership?

Comment: Sorry, typo, corrected now

Comment: In this case, Nikola's answer will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

If by `Subscription` you meant `Membership` then the code below should work

```
$membership= Membership::with('user.images')->findOrFail($id);
```

Comment: `->with('user.images')` would also load users. +1

Answer (score 1):

Try this, No need for extra relation load

```
$membership= Membership::with( 'user.images')->findOrFail($id);

//get users of this membership  with their images
```